# Iphone SDK: Scaling an image every second

Tags: iphone, image, integer, scaling

**How can i scale an image every second by using an integer??**

I want to do something like this:

- I'l have a time which will decrese 0,025 from an integer that i will use to scale my image.
- I will also have another timer which would scale the image.

I want the second timer to do something like that:

MyImage.image.size.width * MyInteger

MyImage.image.size.hight * MyInteger

**How can i make the scaling animation run smooth like the CGTransform Animations?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's far easier to figure out the duration and the target scale factors than your suggested way. Try this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                    turnDeviceView.transform = 
                       myImageView.transform = 
                         CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2);      
                 }];
```

You can even trigger this animation every second, as long as you set the duration less than a second. You can subtract a value from the scale factors to get in the progression you need.